# Comparing (less than) two values different columns not working

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to compare two values on my sheet and the code is not working, although there are values that attend the condition that I am comparing.

The goal is: IF the END_DATE is smaller than the EFF_MTH, then the EFF_MTH should be the END_DATE value.

Can someone please assist? where am I missing the issue?

I added `.all()` as I was receiving the error:

`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Please let me know if there is a better way to handle this. Thanks in advance.

```
df = pd.read_excel (f"C:/Users/Me/Desktop/Cleaned_file - 12-01-22.xlsx")

## REMOVING TIME FROM DATES
df['DATE_START'] = df['DATE_START'].dt.strftime('%d%m%Y')

## Slices only the month
df['END_DATE'] = df['END_DATE'].dt.strftime('%d%m%Y'[2:4])

## Defines eff month based on period column

df.loc[df['PERIOD'] == '3Q', 'EFF_MTH'] = "09"
df.loc[df['PERIOD'] == '1H', 'EFF_MTH'] = "06"
df.loc[df['PERIOD'] == '2Q', 'EFF_MTH'] = "06"
df.loc[df['PERIOD'] == '1Q', 'EFF_MTH'] = "03"
df.loc[df['PERIOD'] == '2H', 'EFF_MTH'] = "12"
df.loc[df['PERIOD'] == '4Q', 'EFF_MTH'] = "12"

## comparing end month with eff month

if df['END_DATE'].all() < df['EFF_MTH'].all():
    df['EFF_MTH']== df['END_DATE']
```

Comment: Why do you use `.all()`?

Comment: what would you expect `df['END_DATE'].all()`  to return?

Comment: because I have the error below when I tried without the .all()



ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Any advise on this?

Thank you.

Comment: Please make a [mre] including some example data, minimal code, and desired output. It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish here, especially since the if-block has another comparison between the same two columns (`==`). For specifics, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341). For more tips, like how to write a good title, see [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean `if (df['END_DATE'] < df['EFF_MTH']).all()`?

But what you want to do is:

```
df['EFF_MTH'] = np.where(df['END_DATE'] > df['EFF_MTH'], df['END_DATE'], df['EFF_MTH'])
```

Comment: That worked! but actually is:

```df['EFF_MTH'] = np.where(df['END_DATE'] < df['EFF_MTH'], df['END_DATE'], df['EFF_MTH'])```

 Thank you very much!

Comment: No need to use NumPy, Pandas has this built-in: `df['EFF_MTH'].mask(df['END_DATE'] > df['EFF_MTH'], df['END_DATE'])`. And [`.where()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) is also a thing.